# Implementing real-time variable fractional delay line in Matlab

Tags: audio, delay, audio-processing

I am attempting to implement a fractional delay line in Matlab which operates in real time, uses an object-oriented approach, and whose length can be modulated each time a sample is processed. I have already successfully implemented a fractional delay line, but I am having some trouble with the modulation step.

Below are some graphs of my current output:

[image: Sawtooth Input Test]

[image: Shows how buffer is changing]

As you can see, discontinuities occur when the current position approaches a part of the buffer which has not been encountered yet, due to the changing length of the buffer. I am wondering if anyone may know of a way to smooth these discontinuities out. My delay line uses linear interpolation at the moment, and I was thinking of using the first-order all pass filter interpolation method instead, but I am not sure if that would help at all, so I wanted to seek some advice first.

The end goal is to have this be a flanger effect for audio, so if anyone has expertise on this particular topic it would be greatly appreciated.

Some specifics for graph interpretation:

- LFO period: 2 seconds
- LFO shape: triangle
- Base delay time: 8 ms
- Max delay time: 18 ms

Process function for delay line:

```
function xDelayed = process(obj, x, L)

    % Current position index
    i = obj.currentPos;

    % Modulate delay time
    L_int = floor(L);
    obj.bufferLen = L_int+1;
    obj.delta = L-L_int;
    obj.delayLen = L;

    % Output delayed sample
    if i < obj.bufferLen
        xDelayed = obj.delta*obj.buffer(i)+(1-obj.delta)*obj.buffer(i+1);
    else
        xDelayed = obj.delta*obj.buffer(i)+(1-obj.delta)*obj.buffer(1);
    end

    % Save current sample to buffer
    obj.buffer(i) = x;

    % Increment delay line or go back to beginning if currently at
    % last position
    if i >= obj.bufferLen
        obj.currentPos = 1;
    else
        obj.currentPos = i+1;
    end
end
```

Any advice on how to handle these discontinuities or improve my implementation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you, and please let me know if you need any additional information. I apologize if what I posted here is not sufficient.

Comment: *"real-time"* and *"MATLAB"* together sound a bit funky to me.  are you building a MATLAB user interface (that's real time)?  but are you operating on a real-time signal?

Comment: probably the simplest good method to do precision delay is with a Kaiser-windowed sinc function.  do you understand how to use the Nyquist-Shannon sampling and reconstruction theorem to accomplish a precision delay?

Comment: I am building code that works in real-time in MATLAB (by processing one sample at a time) that will eventually either have a user interface or be ported to C++. I have not heard of precision delays before, but I will look in to this. Thank you.

Comment: i tried to get to a [mathematically formal answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17978/comb-filter-attenuation/18389#18389) (that can be translated into code of any language) before.  check that out, maybe.